# redux-form: override the field's onChange() function

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to use the [DropZone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) component in my reactjs-based app for uploading multiple files. There is field called `pics` for my redux-form, and the following works for uploading a single file:

**in the render() function:**

```
<Row>
                  <Dropzone
                     { ...pics }
                     onDrop={ this.dropFile }
                 >
                   <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                 </Dropzone>
              </Row>
```

**My dropFile() function**:

```
dropFile(files, evt) {
        console.log('received files: ', files);
        this.props.fields.pics.onChange(files); // use *files* to update the field pics value here        
    }
```

Although uploading a single file works, it does not allow uploading multiple files (dropped multiple files into DropZone). I guess the reason is the `onChange` function overwrites the previous file(s), so I was wondering if it's possible to override the **onChange** function on a certain field in redux-form.

**Edit:**

In a hacky way, I have the reducer listen to the `redux-form/CHANGE` event, but I would like to know if there's any better way. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping UI components to use with Redux Form, and use custom onChange event functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080050/wrapping-ui-components-to-use-with-redux-form-and-use-custom-onchange-event-fun)